# Dynamic partitioning for Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to create a Kinesis delivery stream on AWS CLI, partitioning the output based on the field created_at, which is a string. I get the following error message:

> An error occurred (InvalidArgumentException) when calling the
> CreateDeliveryStream operation: S3 Prefix should contain Dynamic
> Partitioning namespaces when Dynamic Partitioning is enabled

I am new to AWS and I am struggling to fix the error. Can someone help?

My JSON looks as follows:

```json
{
    "DeliveryStreamName": "KDS-S3-silver",
    "DeliveryStreamType": "KinesisStreamAsSource",
    "KinesisStreamSourceConfiguration": {
        "KinesisStreamARN": "my-stream",
        "RoleARN": "my-role"
    },
    "ExtendedS3DestinationConfiguration": {
        "RoleARN": "my-role",
        "BucketARN": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-transformed",
        "Prefix": "created_at=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:created_at}/",
        "ErrorOutputPrefix": "error/result=!{firehose:error-output-type}/!{timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd}",
        "BufferingHints" : {
            "IntervalInSeconds" : 60,
            "SizeInMBs" : 64
          },
        "CompressionFormat": "UNCOMPRESSED",
        "ProcessingConfiguration": {
            "Enabled": true,
            "Processors": [
                {
                    "Parameters" : [ {
                        "ParameterName" : "LambdaArn",
                        "ParameterValue" : "lambda-test"
                      }],
                    "Type" : "Lambda"
                  },
                  {
                    "Parameters" : [ {
                        "ParameterName" : "MetadataExtractionQuery",
                        "ParameterValue" : "{created_at:.data.created_at| strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')| strftime('%Y%m%d')}"
                      },
                      {
                        "ParameterName" : "JsonParsingEngine",
                        "ParameterValue" : "JQ-1.6"
                      }
                    ],
                    "Type" : "MetadataExtraction"
                  }
            ]
        },
        "S3BackupMode": "Enabled",
        "S3BackupConfiguration": {
            "RoleARN": "my-role",
            "BucketARN": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-raw",
            "Prefix": "created_at=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:created_at}/",
            "ErrorOutputPrefix": "error/result=!{firehose:error-output-type}/!{timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd}"
        },
        "DynamicPartitioningConfiguration": {
            "Enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

How should the prefix be specified in order to avoid the error?

Comment: I am not sure if you want to check this:- "If a prefix ends with a slash, it appears as a folder in the Amazon S3 bucket", so maybe try removing the end slash in the prefix it doesn't correspond to a folder in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You should have added Dynamic Partitioning namespace to the prefix field like below:

```py
# yours.
"Prefix": "created_at=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:created_at}/",

# right version.
"Prefix": "env=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:<any_column_that_can_be_used_as_namespace>}/created_at=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:created_at}/",

# or maybe you can use "created_at" column as namespace directly.
"Prefix": "env=!{partitionKeyFromQuery:created_at}/",
```